# My dog covers food and water bowls with sand

Tags: diet, stress

we just built a new home.  We brought our Staffie, Bella, to house last weekend (7 days ago) for a pre-moving in overnight stay so she can get to know the environment. Those 2 days she looked depreseed and developed diahorea and would not eat.  Last night we brought her for her first night.  We put her doghouse right by the back door and her food and water bowls next to it.  I got up at 4am to get her indoors before sunrise.  I saw that she had completely covered her food and water bowls with sand.  When she heard me call, she came out of her doghouse and covered her food with more sand before coming to me.  Very weird.  I believe this can be stress??  What can I do to help her relax and settle in with us?  The boundary walls are not yet done, so we keep her indoors most of the time (she loves running outside) and take for walks.

I hope she is okay.  Don't know what I can do for her.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If she is used to running around but can't do this any more, I suggest taking her on a lot more walks than she usually gets. Letting her sleep with you for a few days until she is more accustomed to the place may also help. Moving her food/water bowls to a place where she can't cover it with things might encourage her to eat. Give her a lot of love, but don't change things too quickly it might stress her out more.

It is also possible that the new place may have a bug that she caught, if the diarrhoea lasts longer than a week or the not eating last longer than a few days, take her to a vet. They should be able to also help with helping with cheering her up.